# Регулярное выражение для текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения, powershell

Подскажите, как убрать только первое "-" в строках:

```
60.125-Sample Data Point - AQL -> 60.125 Sample Data Point - AQL
54.09-E-Procedure Execution_03 -> 54.09 E-Procedure Execution_03
```

с помощью регулярного выражения?

Comment: В чём работаете (программа, язык программирования)?

Comment: Ипспользую Powershell

Comment: `-replace '^([^-]*)-','$1'` удаляем первый тире через реплейс, записываем все символы с начала строки отличные от символа `-` в группу, потом за группой `-` и заменяем все это на захваченную группу `$1`

Comment: получилось так 60.125Sample Data Point - AQL, пробела не хватает после 60.125

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Powershell для удаления первого вхождения любого шаблона можно воспользоваться методом `Replace` объекта `[Regex]`:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> $R = [Regex]"-"
PS C:\Users\admin> $R.Replace($str, ' ', 1)
60.125 Sample Data Point - AQL
```

**Подробности**

- `$R = [Regex]"-"` - в переменной `$R` задаётся шаблон `-`
- `$R.Replace($str, ' ', 1)` - находит `1` совпадение (первое) в строке `$str`  и заменяет его пробелом.

Если заменить аргумент *count* с `1` на `2`, будут заменены первые два совпадения.

См. [справку MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Int32_) по `Regex.Repalce(String, String, Int32)`.

Comment: Спасибо, так вроде работает